# Intermittent failure with Office SMTP server

Tags: c#, smtp, office365

I'm sending about 2-3000 email a day using Office 365 smtp server.  99% of the emails are sent correctly but about 1% of the time I get the following error :

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM.

Here is my code :

```
private void SendEmail(string strTo, string strFrom, string strMessage, string strSubject, bool htmlFormat = true)
{
    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    System.Net.Mail.MailAddress mto = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(strTo);
    System.Net.Mail.MailAddress mfrom = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(strFrom);
    mail.Subject = strSubject;
    mail.From = mfrom;
    mail.To.Add(mto);
    mail.Body = strMessage;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = htmlFormat;
    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient mailClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 587);
    mailClient.Timeout = 1000000;
    mailClient.EnableSsl = true;
    mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    mailClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("my@emailaddress.com", "mypassword");
    mailClient.Send(mail);
}
```

Someone have an idea why this is happening so intermittently?!

Comment: do you do this through loop in your code? or do you use batching for sending this large number of emails?

Comment: Mails are in a queue and I'm sending max 10 emails per minutes

Answer (score 1):

This is not a code issue, you need to know how many receipts do you send from your client app per day and not the number of emails.

An email may contain more than one recipient. So if you send 2 emails and each contains 4 receipts, you are sending 8 emails. Then compare this number to the max. number emails per day for your o365 subscription.

Please check out recipient rate limit, recipient limit and message rate limit per subscription.

Check out these limits here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange-online-limits.aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: emails are in a queue and are limited to 10 emails per minutes.  Our account tolerate 30 mails per minute so we are safe.  We never send emails to multiple recipient.  I also think it's not a code issue.  I was thinking about a network issue but we are hosted on a top end cloud service.

Comment: Try to catch network and SMTP exceptions before the general purpose exception to nail down what type of exception is thrown in details. it might be a network issue which causes the app to lose the authentication token you have for an established connection with the mail server.